trying to verify my jwt token that send by a another server
i have a sveltekit application and i use oauth2 to auth users.when users are loggin if there is no jwt token i create a new one
const login = await event.locals.auth();

    if (login) {
        const authCookie = event.cookies.get('authCookie');

        if (new Date(login.expires) > new Date()) {
            if (!authCookie) {
                const jwt = jsonwebtoken.sign({ email: login.user?.email }, `${process.env.AUTH_JWT}`);

                console.log(jwt)

                const expirationDate = new Date();
                expirationDate.setMonth(expirationDate.getMonth() + 1);

                event.cookies.set('authCookie', jwt, {
                    httpOnly: true,
                    secure: true,
                    sameSite: 'strict',
                    path: '/',
                    expires: expirationDate
                });
            }
        } else {
            if (!authCookie) {
                event.cookies.delete('authCookie', { path: '/' });
            }
        }
    } else {
        event.cookies.delete('authCookie', { path: '/' });
    }

and i have spring boot application as a data access layer i send my jwt token with it as a beara token. in spring appllication i try to verify my token
@PostMapping("/api/createNewFavorite")
    public FavoriteModel CreateNewFavorite(@RequestBody FavoriteModel favoriteModel , @RequestHeader HttpHeaders httpHeaders){

        String jwtBearerToken = Objects.requireNonNull(httpHeaders.get("authorization")).get(0);
        String jwt = jwtBearerToken.split(" ")[1];

        String  secretString = "u2nv8bk5c3y9pl7h6f9o28jn0c4xsmua";

        SecretKey authKey = Keys.hmacShaKeyFor(secretString.getBytes());

        Jws<Claims> parsed = Jwts.parser().verifyWith(authKey).build().parseSignedClaims(jwt);

        Claims claims = parsed.getPayload();

        System.out.println(claims);

        return createFavorite.CreateNewFavorite(favoriteModel);
    }

but it give's error
JWT signature does not match locally computed signature. JWT validity cannot be asserted and should not be trusted.
How can i fix this.and is there any way to improve this. I'm trying to learn how spring boot work.
Edit:
String  secretString = "u2nv8bk5c3y9pl7h6f9o28jn0c4xsmua"; this is the key i use to sign the jwt in sveltekit
const jwt = jsonwebtoken.sign({ email: login.user?.email }, `${process.env.AUTH_JWT}`);
process.env.AUTH_JWT = u2nv8bk5c3y9pl7h6f9o28jn0c4xsmua
Thank you!
Edit:found answer
if (login) {
    const authCookie = event.cookies.get('authCookie');

    if (new Date(login.expires) > new Date()) {
        if (!authCookie) {

            const jwt = jsonwebtoken.sign({ email: login.user?.email }, `my secret key`);

            console.log(jwt)

            const expirationDate = new Date();
            expirationDate.setMonth(expirationDate.getMonth() + 1);

            event.cookies.set('authCookie', jwt, {
                httpOnly: true,
                secure: true,
                sameSite: 'strict',
                path: '/',
                expires: expirationDate
            });
        }
    } else {
        if (!authCookie) {
            event.cookies.delete('authCookie', { path: '/' });
        }
    }
} else {
    event.cookies.delete('authCookie', { path: '/' });
}

my env file didn't load properly
spring application
`` @PostMapping("/api/createNewFavorite")
public FavoriteModel CreateNewFavorite(@RequestBody FavoriteModel favoriteModel , @RequestHeader HttpHeaders httpHeaders){
    try {

        String jwtBearerToken = Objects.requireNonNull(httpHeaders.get("authorization")).get(0);
        String jwt = jwtBearerToken.split(" ")[1];

        String secretString = "secret key";

        SecretKey authKey = Keys.hmacShaKeyFor(secretString.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

        Jws<Claims> parsed = Jwts.parser().verifyWith(authKey).build().parseSignedClaims(jwt);

        Claims claims = parsed.getPayload();

        System.out.println(claims);

        return createFavorite.CreateNewFavorite(favoriteModel);
    }catch (SignatureException error){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Error"+error);
    }
}

``

where did you get the secretString = "u2nv8bk5c3y9pl7h6f9o28jn0c4xsmua" ?

that is my signature that i encode jwt in svelte "const jwt = jsonwebtoken.sign({ email: login.user?.email }, ${process.env.AUTH_JWT});"
